# Method of p value correction for a set of dependent p values

Tags: multiple-comparisons, p-value

I just got a list of 100 p-values, some of which are associated. For details, these 100 p-values could be separated into 7 groups, each group was calculated from a expression dataset. However, these datasets had 10%~60% overlap among each other, that is the pvalues inside a dataset were independent, but were not across the dataset, which bring the whole 100 p-values not independent.

So is there any solutions you know to directly and simply solve this? Some ref. pointed out to use the BH adjustment inside the R package, while choosing a loose criteria, e.g. 0.2, to define the significance level.

```
tmp$V7 = p.adjust(tmp$V6,method="BY")
tmpV6[1:5]
[1] 0.040461040 0.001250268 0.037407030 0.009361665 0.006866937
tmpV7[1:5]
[1] 0.31423224 0.08659423 0.29570166 0.14456543 0.13611251
tmp$V7 = p.adjust(tmp$V6,method="BH")
tmp$V6[1:5]
[1] 0.040461040 0.001250268 0.037407030 0.009361665 0.006866937
tmp$V7[1:5]
[1] 0.05252837 0.01447545 0.04943072 0.02416616 0.02275313
```

Please take a look at this, `tmp$V6` is the original p-value, while `tmp$V7` is after correction.

However, it seems that after BY correction, I get even worse result than BH (or fdr) method.

Comment: What are you going to do with the results? What are your inferential objectives? Is this a preliminary study intended to guide further experimentation?

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely correct for multiple comparisons! There are a huge number of strategies for this, many of which are suitable for dependent data. The Benjamini–Hochberg–Yekutieli procedure is computationally simple approach to setting the false discovery rate and works under arbitrary dependence assumptions; your tests don't need to be independent for it to be appropriate.

In brief, perform all $m$ of your individual tests, recording the $p$-values as you go. Sort them from smallest to largest, creating a list $p_1 \ldots p_m.$ Find the largest value of $k$ such that:
$$ p_k \le \alpha \cdot \frac{k}{m \cdot c(m)}$$
where $c(m)=1$ if the tests are independent or positively correlated, or for arbitrary dependence $c(m) = \sum_i^m \frac{1}{i} \approx \ln(m) + \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant (0.5772...).

Accept as significant all the $p$-values less than or equal to $p_k$, but reject the rest as non-significant.

Note that this is somewhat more liberal (i.e., has better power, but more Type I errors) than something which controls the Familywise Error Rate. However, people typically use the same $\alpha$ value (0.05, 0.01, etc). Setting $\alpha=0.2$ seems like it would be asking for a lot of spurious calls!

Further reading:

- [Wikipedia Page on FDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate)
- [Benjamini and Yekutieli (2001). "The control of the false discovery rate in multiple testing under dependency" Annals of Statistics 29 (4): 1165–1188.](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Eybenja/MyPapers/benjamini_yekutieli_ANNSTAT2001.pdf)
- ["Comparison Shopping" for False Discovery Rate packages in R](http://strimmerlab.org/notes/fdr.html)

Comment: si here the p-value vector sorted ? otherwise the formula you propose is difficult to understand as you need to find the max k.

Comment: @NicolasRosewick Yes! Edited into the answer.

Comment: I don't see any description of the intended inferences in the question and so it does not seem at all reasonable to say that 'correction' for multiplicity is "definitely" appropriate. This sounds like a preliminary investigation where the interesting comparisons can be taken as the start of a more directed study. Type I error rates are not a very useful yardstick for evaluation of a preliminary study.